# Getting row position with multiple MySQL queries and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table like the following:

```
id | player | game 1 | game 2 | game 3
--------------------------------------
1  | Joe    | 345    | 34     | 64    
2  | Mark   | 12     | 256    | 35
3  | Dan    | 156    | 134    | 122
```

The table has about 20K entries.
Columns "game 1","game 2", "game 3" contain player's points for each of the games.

I need to create one page for each of the players, where I show their ranking position in game 1, game 2, game 3. All in one page.

First of all, I don't know how to get the ranking position of a user... For example if I want to output Joe's rank for game 1, of course I can do an ORDERBY 'game 1', but how do I get Joe's rank then?

Second: is it possible to get Joe's rank for game 1, game 2 and game 3 in a single query or do I have to do 3 separate queries?

Thank you for your help, really appreciated.

Comment: `"but how do I get Joe's rank"` - Take a look at the `WHERE` keyword.  Something like: `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE player = 'Joe'`  (Which, by the way, would preclude any need for an `ORDER BY` since you're identifying a single record.)

Comment: What does `ORDER BY` have to do with the question?  It looks like the information you want is simply in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to put an ID column in there that auto increments everytime a player is added. Then pull the row based on the id of the user.

USING PDO

```
//Set your user Id somehow.. Maybe from a session or from your URL
$userId = trim(strip_tags($_GET['userId']));

//Then query your db and order by game 1 descending from highest score down to 0

$user_sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT player, game 1, game 2, game 3 FROM players ORDER BY game 1 DESC")
$user_sth->execute();

//start the rank at 1
$rank = 1;

//create a variable to store our results in
$results = '';

//fetch the result array
while($user = $user_sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){
    //maybe put it into a table row
    $results .= '<tr><td>'.$rank.'</td><td>'.$user['player'].'</td><td>'.$user['game 1'].'</td></tr>';

    //update our rank position number
    $rank++;
}
```

now you can echo $results somewhere in your html

Comment: And ID column isn't entirely necessary if `player` already identifies the record.

Comment: @David true, I just thought it may be a good idea if he is not forcing unique player names

Comment: Yes I have unique IDs, I omitted in my table. I read your answer and it seems very good, you show me a good trick for OO queries, but I think it will output the content of the game 1, game 2, game 3 column. Probably I was not clear in my description: the content of those columns are player points: I need to order them to get the position. This is my question.

Comment: @marcello, see my edits and let me know if that is what you are looking for.